# How to install single packages in a workspace?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, installation, catkin, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In our project we have certain packages that are custom and required to run our system, but which do not need to be rebuilt during everyday development. I would like to designate them to be "installed", so that they are built from source, but `catkin clean` does not remove them.

I know that you can call `make install` in the `build` directory of your workspace (and in single packages) as described in the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment) to create packages in the `install` directory, but as it is also deleted by `catkin clean`, I don't see the use.

I found [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/295462/how-to-properly-install-packages-from-source/) and [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/252478/how-to-build-a-package-from-source-on-ubuntu-mate-1604-lts-and-ros-kinetic/) answer, but they seem to deal with building from source, not with "installing" in the sense that I mean it. There are also other questions like [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/70321/how-to-install-package-from-source-in-groovy/), but they seem to either not apply or be outdated.

- Can single packages in a workspace be installed so that `catkin clean` does not remove them? If yes, how is it done using the `catkin` tools?
- If it is not possible, what is the canonical way to deal with this? Build the packages to be installed in an intermediate workspace, and then extend another workspace? Build them in `/opt/ros/melodic/`?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330040/how-to-install-single-packages-in-a-workspace?/) by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2180 on 2019-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"installing" something (either with `catkin_make` or with `catkin_tools`) will always copy installable artefacts to the `install` space. With `catkin_tools`, `catkin clean` does indeed clear that directory out, unless you specify specific spaces to be deleted only (ie: with `--log`, `--build`, `--devel` and/or `--install`).

That is rather brittle though (if/when someone forgets to pass those options your `install` space will be cleaned out again).

> If it is not possible, what is the canonical way to deal with this? Build the packages to be installed in an intermediate workspace, and then extend another workspace? Build them in `/opt/ros/melodic/`?

Best practice would be -- apart from using an internal buildfarm, releasing those packages and installing them that way -- to create an *underlay* workspace that your regular workspace extends. You'd use [workspace overlaying](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying), like so:

```
/opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO
└── /path/to/your/underlay_ws
    └── /path/to/your/regular_ws
```

In this setup, vanilla `$ROS_DISTRO` would be the install space populated by the `.deb` packages you install using `apt` (or built from sources on some platforms). You then build the underlay workspace with the packages that you "always need". You then activate the underlay workspace (either `source /path/to/your/underlay_ws/install/setup.bash` or by using `catkin config --extend` (recommended)) and build your `regular_ws`.

A `catkin clean` of `regular_ws` will only clean out your regular workspace. It will not touch any underlays.

Finally:

- `underlay_ws` can of course have any name, it doesn't need to be called `underlay_ws`
- it can also be located anywhere (here in my lab we have several underlays which are located in `/opt/ros` fi)
- if you have machines that are exact duplicates of each other, you could even share your underlay workspaces, avoiding the need to build the workspaces on all machines (but if you go this far, you might start looking into generating `.deb`s)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2019-08-07**:
Thanks. Very helpful as always. I extended our workspace and it worked on first try.